# Getting 401 from Google user info endpoint

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-oauth, userinfo

I am trying to get users to authorize the app for "offline" access.

I have the token url as "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token". I hit that with params such as the one-time `code`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `scopes` etc to get a response containing tokens. It looks like the below:

```
{
  access_token: ...,
  expires_in: 3599,
  refresh_token: ...,
  scope: ...,
  token_type: 'Bearer'
}
```

I take the access_token value from the above response and try to use it to pull `userInfo` from "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json" and it is always returning 401.

I did it with code and curl, trying to pass the token in the authorization header as

```
const headers = {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
};
const userInfo = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json',{headers});
```

and also tried to add the access_token to the query string, as well as executing against newer endpoints such as `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json` and `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/userinfo?alt=json`.

I am always getting 401. The message is: `Request is missing required authentication credentials...`

What should I be doing instead?

Comment: If you have the value for the access token, can you reproduce the issue with a simple cURL command:

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer youraccesstokenhere" "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json"

Comment: I don't want to keep reproducing the issue. I need to know why it is not working as I want it, so I could fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The userinfo end point is a HTTP GET call you can string the access token as a query parameter.

```
https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo?access_token=ya29.a0AfH6SMDfRQFdEOxq97LXqUa1jwdtRLSD2l_hiLFeaWYXRBB6gIkh7XHko75xj70uPnuOppKtf0c
```

Response

```
{
  "sub": "1172004755326746",
  "name": "Linda Lawton",
  "given_name": "Linda",
  "family_name": "Lawton",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhroCYJp2P9xeYeYk1npchBPK-zbtTxzNQo0WAHI20\u003ds96-c",
  "locale": "en"
}
```

BTW you may want to consider using the [people api](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) in stead its much more stable then the userinfo endpoint.